# Save Json Array in Spring Framework

Tags: java, json, spring

In my project, I use the spring framework and a database for logging indicators with esp8266. Because the measurement frequency is too high (~100 milliseconds) I decided to send Json data as an array. Like this one:

```
[
    {
        "voltage":1111,
        "amperage":1111
    },
    {
        "voltage":2222,
        "amperage":2222
    } 
]
```

When trying to send data, the controller could not process the data. and issued such an error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.INA219.INA219.models.DataModel` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)]
```

As far as I understand, I need to save each element of the json array as a separate object. How can I do this?

Controller method

```
@PostMapping("/addData")
    public ResponseEntity addData(@RequestBody DataModel dataModell){
        try {
            dataServicez.saveData(dataModell);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
        } catch (Exception e){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Ошибка");
        }
```

Service method

```
public DataModel saveData(DataModel dataModel){
        DataModel _dataModel = new DataModel(dataModel.getId(),dataModel.getAmperage(),dataModel.getVoltage());
        return dataRepo.save(_dataModel);
    }
```

Part of the data model class (all other methods in the class are automatically generated getter and setter, and default constructors)

```
public class DataModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "amperage")
    private Double amperage;
    @Column(name = "voltage")
    private Double voltage;
...
```

Comment: In the RequestBody you should expect a DataModel[] not a DataModel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is expecting a single object in the request body, but you're sending an array of objects. To process the array of JSON objects, you need to change your method signature to accept a List instead of a single DataModel. Here's how you could do it:

```
@PostMapping("/addData")
public ResponseEntity addData(@RequestBody List<DataModel> dataModels){
    try {
        dataServicez.saveData(dataModels);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
    } catch (Exception e){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Ошибка");
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public List<DataModel> saveData(List<DataModel> dataModels){
    List<DataModel> savedDataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataModel dataModel : dataModels) {
        DataModel _dataModel = new DataModel(dataModel.getId(), dataModel.getAmperage(), dataModel.getVoltage());
        savedDataModels.add(dataRepo.save(_dataModel));
    }
    return savedDataModels;
}
```